# Image compression problem

Tags: theming, media, files

I keep on running into an issue with image compression on Drupal.

I have a set of good quality, clear images, that I'm resizing down to 100px by 100px in CSS.

When I resize, the quality worsens and the images look blurry. The site uses GD2 compression enabled at 100%, but this setting doesn't seem to have any effect.

The image style is set to scale and crop at 365px by 365px.

Anything I could be missing?

Comment: CSS and GD have nothing to do with each other. GD is for creating a new image file from an existing image file, while changing the size (and or making other edits), while CSS takes the image that is delivered from the server, and tells the browser how many pixels it should be rendered in. When you examine the image being shown in the browser, what are the actual dimensions of the image?

Comment: Do not use CSS to "size" images. Use Image Styles in Drupal.